# MPI rank determination

Tags: mpi

I am new to MPI and I often see the following codes in MPI code:

```
if (rank == 0) {
    MPI_Send(buf, len, MPI_CHAR, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
else {
    MPI_Recv(buf, len, MPI_CHAR, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
}
```

It seems that the rank determines which process is sending and which process is receiving. But
how is the rank of a process determined by calling `MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);`? 
Is it related to the command line arguments for `mpirun` ? 
For example:

```
mpirun -n 2 -host localhost1,localhost2 ./a.out
```

(`localhost1` is rank 0 and `localhost2` is rank 1?) 
How is the program going to determine who has rank 0 and who has rank 1? 
Is there a way for me to specify something such that say `localhost1` is sending and `localhost2` is receiving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, if you're trying to think about communication in your MPI program based on physical processors/machines, you're not going about it in the right way. Most of the time, it doesn't matter which actual machine each rank is mapped to. All that matters is that you call `mpiexec` or `mpirun` (they're usually the same thing), something inside your MPI implementation starts up `n` processes which could be located locally, remotely, or some combination of the two, and assigns them ranks. Theoretically those ranks could be assigned arbitrarily, though it's usually in some predictable way (often something like round-robin over the entire group of hosts that are available). Inside your program, it usually makes very little difference whether you're running rank 0 on `host0` or `host1`. The important thing is that you are doing specific work on rank 0, that requires communication from rank 1.

That being said, there are more rare times where it might be important which rank is mapped to which processor. Examples might be:

1. If you have GPUs on some nodes and not others and you need certain ranks to be able to control a GPU.
2. You need certain processes to be mapped to the same physical node to optimize communication patterns for things like shared memory.
3. You have data staged on certain hosts that needs to map to specific ranks.

These are all advanced examples. Usually if you're in one of these situations, you've been using MPI long enough to know what you need to do here, so I'm betting that you're probably not in this scenario.

Just remember, it doesn't really matter where my ranks are. It just matters that I have the right number of them.

**Disclaimer:** All of that being said, it does matter that you launch the correct number of processes. What I mean by that is, if you have 2 hosts that each have a single quad-core processor, it doesn't make sense to start a job with 16 ranks. You'll end up spending all of your computational time context switching your processes in and out. Try not to have more ranks than you have compute cores.

Answer (score 1):

When you call mpirun there is a process manager which determine the node/rank attribution of your process. I suggest you to have a look at [Controlling Process Placement with the Intel MPI library](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/controlling-process-placement-with-the-intel-mpi-library)  and for openmpi 
 check [-npernode, -pernode](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.4/man1/mpirun.1.php) options.
Use this [Hello world test](http://mpitutorial.com/mpi-hello-world/) to check if this is what you want.

You can also just simply change the condition (rank==1) if you want to switch your process works.